# Push notification without background service in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, socket.io

In our android app, its background service has a socket connection to our node js server. The connection will keep alive as long as there is an internet connection. **When socket receives message from node js, it will construct and display the notification if the app is not opened.**

Running the background service seems to be a bad practice to me, especially it will send a heartbeat for every 15 seconds. **We are searching for an alternate way to push notification without background service** e.g. iOS has a notification center to handle this.

We had tried other services such as firebase and parse, unfortunately we didn't have any luck and it seems to be a mission impossible to us. I have tried to kill the whatsapp background service and indeed no message will be received unless I open the application.

**Please let me know if there is any method to push notification without service running in the background**. Your help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: @FreFernando Tan do you get any better idea without using background services ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its is not possible. I have used SignanR as well in that background service is required. If you implement Service in correct way then there is no problem at all. Other alternative is sending SMS to user so that you can get received message in Broadcast receiver but again it costly like to purchase SMS gateway.